# limiting search results function snippet jquery

Tags: jquery

I am currently working on the search function to show the results in real-time

**PROBLEM**

I need to limit the maximum results displayed, in this example to `4`

I tried using `ul.length < 4` but it is not working

By default, the number of li displayed is 4 and when searching, as well 4. (will be set to a higher number later)

```js
$("#search_emotions").on("input",function(){
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = $("#search_emotions");
  filter = input.val();
  ul = $("#emotions");
   
  ul.find('li').each(function(){
      var a = $(this).find("div").text();
      if( a.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          $(this).css("display", "");
      } else {
          $(this).css("display", "none");
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text id='search_emotions'  placeholder="Search emotions" />

<ul class="emotions" id="emotions">
<li ><div class="emotion_1">A</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_2">B</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_3">CF</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_4">DE</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_5">E</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_6">FA</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_7">GB</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_8">H1C</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_9">HC2</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_10">HC3</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_11">HC4</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_12">HC5</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_13">HC6</div></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a counter to calculate the number of li displayed

```js
var limit = 4;
var initialLimit = 5;
$("#search_emotions").on("input",function(){
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = $("#search_emotions");
  filter = input.val();
  ul = $("#emotions");
  
  var counter = 0;
  var limitNum = filter == "" ? initialLimit : limit;
  
  ul.find('li').each(function(){
      var a = $(this).find("div").text();
      var condition = counter < limitNum;
      
      if( a.indexOf(filter) > -1 && condition) {
          $(this).css("display", "");
          counter++;
      } else {
          $(this).css("display", "none");
      }
  });
});

$('#search_emotions').trigger('input')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text id='search_emotions'  placeholder="Search emotions" />

<ul class="emotions" id="emotions">
<li ><div class="emotion_1">A</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_2">B</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_3">CF</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_4">DE</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_5">E</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_6">FA</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_7">GB</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_8">H1C</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_9">HC2</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_10">HC3</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_11">HC4</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_12">HC5</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_13">HC6</div></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: works great when the search is active...but how do I limit the number of lis displayed at initializing? In this case appears all the values `ABCFDEEFAGBH1CHC2HC3HC4HC5HC6`

Comment: when initializing, how many `li` you want to display? all of them or same as limit number?

Comment: since there should be limited when initializing, i added a trigger to `$('#search_emotions')`